# UNION SELECT to get ID's from news and page (A database error occurred: Every derived table must have its own alias)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union

I'm trying to get the ID's of found items via a custom query. To avoid double results because of searching in 2 tables I understood that I should use UNION.

I wrote this little query:

```
SELECT * FROM( SELECT `news_item`.`id` as nId, `news_item`.`title`, `news_item`.`content` FROM `news_item` ni UNION SELECT `page_item`.`id` as pId, `page_item`.`title`, `page_item`.`content` FROM `page_item` pi ) WHERE `news_item`.`title` LIKE '%serious%' OR `news_item`.`content` LIKE '%serious%' OR `page_item`.`title` LIKE '%serious%' OR `page_item`.`content` LIKE '%serious%' LIMIT 0, 4
```

Which results in an SQL error: `A database error occurred: Every derived table must have its own alias`

I've tried using aliasses(As ni and pi. Also for the select values(ie. ni.title).) and tried without aliases, to no avail.

Here's the PHP:

```
$searchTerms = array();
foreach($searchWords as $word){
    $searchTerms[] = "`news_item`.`title` LIKE '".$word."'";
    $searchTerms[] = "`news_item`.`content` LIKE '".$word."'";

    $searchTerms[] = "`page_item`.`title` LIKE '".$word."'";
    $searchTerms[] = "`page_item`.`content` LIKE '".$word."'";
}
$newsAndPageItemsQry = "
SELECT 
    *
FROM(
        SELECT `news_item`.`id` as nId, `news_item`.`title`, `news_item`.`content` FROM `news_item` ni
        UNION 
        SELECT `page_item`.`id` as pId, `page_item`.`title`, `page_item`.`content` FROM `page_item` pi
)
WHERE
    " . implode(" OR ", $searchTerms) . "
LIMIT
    " . $scope;
```

**Instant edit:** When I give the initial `FROM` an alias I get the database error: `A database error occurred: Unknown column 'news_item.id' in 'field list'`. It exists. Definitely.

My question basically: How can I search in page_item and news_item to get the ID's for my keywords in title and content without getting duplicate results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> Unknown column 'news_item.id' in 'field list'. It exists. Definitely.

But it is not true. Your columns are `nId`, `title` and `content`:

```
SELECT 
`news_item`.`id` as nId,   #nId
`news_item`.`title`,       #title
`news_item`.`content`      #content
FROM `news_item` ni
```

Comment: I've got it now :) Used the alias for all the selects. But NOT in the WHERE clause indeed. I thought I needed news_item.title instead of just title. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should create an alias for subquery:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM(
        SELECT `news_item`.`id` as nId, `news_item`.`title`, news_-...
        UNION 
        SELECT `page_item`.`id` as pId, `page_item`.`title`, page_it...
)   T  <---- here!!!
WHERE
    " . implode(" OR ", $searchTerms) . "
LIMIT
    " . $scope
```

Comment: Thanks, I've editted my post right before you posted because I've tried that :) It's not working,

Comment: Then this becomes a new question, You should have opened a new post. I answer in new answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22930935/842935

Answer (score 0):

Use alias name rather than news_item

Like `myAlias.nId=123` or `myAlias.title like '%word%'`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal it does provide the answer. If you read acceptted one and mide you can see thay are the same in fact. Alias fields should be used